# is there compability problem between document.location.href with document.URL?

Tags: javascript

what is the different between document.location.href with document.URL?
is there compability problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Document.URL):

> URL is a replacement for the DOM Level 0 document.location.href property. However, document.location.href is settable, and document.URL is not.

`document.location` is not part of any standard (DOM Level 0) even though most browsers support it. `document.URL` is part of the W3C [DOM Level 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html) specification.

Answer (score 2):

*document.location.href* is **settable**, and *document.URL* is not.

Answer (score 0):

Both Provides the URL of the current document. The value is the same as location.href. The document.URL property evolved as a replacement for document.location to avoid potential confusion (by scripters and JavaScript interpreter engines) between the location object and document.location property. To navigate to another page, it is safest (for cross-browser and backward compatibility) to assign a URL string value to the location.href property, rather than this document-centered property.

Answer (score 0):

since [proper] `location` object belongs (and, more important, should belong there) to `window`, yes to `document.location`, it is a compatibility problem (or, more precise, DOM level 0 quirk).

FAQ entry: http://xkr.us/js/location